# bootstrap tags-input[JS] - can't set (or show) multiple data in suggestion list from dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input, typehead

I create bootstrap tags input with typehead.js but I can't show more than 1 result to dropdown list(suggestion). This is my code to process:

JS:

```js
var tag = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://blog.dev/admin/manager/911/fetch-tags'
    }
});
tag.initialize();

var elt = $("#tags");
elt.tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'tag_name',
        displayKey: 'tag_name',
        valueKey: 'tag_name',
        source: tag.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
            ],
            header: [
                '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"></div>'
            ],
            suggestion: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                    return '<a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="list-group-item">' + data[1].tag_name  + '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="example example_typeahead">
      <input type="text" id="tags" value="Amsterdam,Washington" data-role="tagsinput">
      </div>
```

Result of remote url return this json format:

```html
{
    "name":
    [{"id": 1, "tag_name": "cat"},
    {"id": 2, "tag_name": "dog"},
    {"id": 3, "tag_name": "cow"}]
}
```

and this object return by console.log(data)

```html
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
id:1
tag_name:"cat"
__proto__:Object 
1:Object
id:2
tag_name:"dog"
__proto__:Object
.......
```

and it only show the first result in suggestion list. I want to it
show all the result but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning only one suggestion. This should be the case -

```
            suggestion: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var suggestList = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                suggestList += '<a href="javascrtipt:void(0)" class="list-group-item">' + data[i].tag_name  + '</a> <br/> \n' ;
            }
                return  suggestList;
        }
```

Comment: i have tried it but it only returns in 1 row. and when click it, input only is received the first value.

Comment: UPDATE: i have removed the suggestion template and i do in other way and successfully. thanks